# firebase.auth is not a function v10

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, typeerror, formik

I'm currently working on a React project and following a Udemy course to implement a sign-in form using Formik for form handling and Firebase's authentication function. So far, I've successfully inserted user data into Firebase, but I'm facing an unexpected behavior while testing the form functionality.

Problem:
When testing the sign-in form, I encounter a specific issue: the form does not seem to be submitting or authenticating users correctly. It throws a TypeError -
*firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function*

how I import and export firebase in my firebase.js file

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(firebase);

export{
    auth,
    firebase
}
```

For using the firebase object inside a component I use the following statement to import the file

```
import {firebase, auth} from "../../firebase";

const submitForm = (values)=> { 
        console.log(values);
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        values.email, values.password
                    ).then(()=>{
                        //Successful toast
                        props.history.push('/dashboard');

                    }).catch((errors)=>{
                        setLoading(false);
                        //Show toasts
                        alert("Invalid")

                    })
 }
```

I know the problem is in importing the Auth function properly in my files. I have tried several methods - changing default imports to named imports, reconfiguring my firebase object, importing using 'firebase/compat/auth 'but it is to no avail.

Comment: You're mixing the newer modular syntax of SDK version 9 and above, with the older namespaced syntax - and that's not possible. See the documentation on this [upgrade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) and the questions I linked that cover this same problem.